# Parse json with variable key

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I just came up with challenging problem.

Below is json response where key is variable (a GUID)

How can I parse it? I've tried Google Gson, but that didn't work.

```
{
  "87329751-7493-7329-uh83-739823748596": {
    "type": "work",
    "status": "online",
    "icon": "landline",
    "number": 102,
    "display_number": "+999999999"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question. That JSON is valid according to JSONLint, so you should be able to parse it as JSON.

Comment: agreed.
But problem is randonly generated GUID.

Comment: I've create pojo against it but its doesn't work because each time GUID generated on server side is different and unique.:)

Comment: Have you tried: `Object.keys(obj)`

Comment: Just parse the JSON into maps and arrays and access the stuff the old-fashioned way.  You don't *have* to create custom classes for everything -- most other languages don't do that, and it's meaningless extra work for a simple JSON structure in many cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use Gson, in order to parse your response you can create a custom class representing your JSON data, and then you can use a `Map`.

Note that a `Map<String, SomeObject>` is exactly what your JSON represents, since you have an `object`, containing a pair of `string` and some `object`:

```
{ "someString": {...} }
```

So, first your class containing the JSON data (in *pseudo-code*):

```
class YourClass
  String type
  String status
  String icon
  int number
  String display_number
```

Then parse your JSON response using a `Map`, like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, YourClass>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, YourClass> map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Now you can access all the values using your `Map`, for example:

```
String GUID = map.keySet().get(0);
String type = map.get(GUID).getType();
```

Note: if you only want to get the GUID value, you don't need to create a class `YourClass`, and you can use the same parsing code, but using a generic `Object` in the `Map`, i.e., `Map<String, Object>`.