# Map JSON to Map with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

So my question is kind of a spin-off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895111/3776810). I have a `JSON` response of

```
{ 
  "Key1": {...},
  "Key2": {...} 
}
```

and I would like to map it into an object. Since I can't make a wrapper object for what could be 100+ keys, I'd put it all in a `Map`.

This answer would be great, but I'm not using `GSON` and am having a hard time doing the same thing with Spring's `RestTemplate`. When I'd like to parse it to a map with an object as such:

```
Map<String, RequestObject> map = restTemplate.getForObject("https://example.com/request.json", Map.class);
```

My `RequestObject` becomes a `LinkedHashMap` instead. So `map` becomes a `Map<String, LinkedHashMap>`. Which in turn also seems to be holding more `LinkedHashMaps`. Will I be needing something more complicated like writing my own [Jackson Deserializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers)?

**edit:**

Unlike in [this question (possible duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108887/generics-with-spring-resttemplate), I do not wish to obtain a generic wrapper. The object will always be the same, but the key varies every time. If it were something as the following:

```
{
   "Sample":{
      "Key":"2",
      "Object":{
         "Id":"0"
      }
   }
}
```

I could map it to:

```
class Sample{
    String key;
    CustomObject object;
}

class CustomObject{
    String id;
}
```

But since it's of the following form:

```
{
   "Key1":{
      "Id":"0",
      "Value":"X"
   },
   "Key2":{
      "Id":"1",
      "Value":"Y"
   },
   "Key3":{
      "Id":"2",
      "Value":"Z"
   }
}
```

I'm not so sure how to map it into a useful representation of the objects represented by each key. (Id & Value here). I can't imagine needing to create a class for every key, so transforming it to a map seems a decent idea. This is not what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108887/generics-with-spring-resttemplate) describes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108887/generics-with-spring-resttemplate?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RestTemplate map JSON key-value pair object with with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494143/resttemplate-map-json-key-value-pair-object-with-with-dynamic-keys)